# Using Jquery to hide/unhide the textbox if button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input button , what I want is if a user clicks on the button then textbox should appear.

Below is the code which is not working :

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Second Driver" id="driver" />
                    <input type="text" id="text" />

$("#driver").click(function() {

    $('#text').show();

  }
 });
```

Also the textbox should not be visible initially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#driver").click(function(){
       $("#text").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: give both of them in one 'div' and do slidetoggle for that 'div' instead of 'textbox'

Answer (score 3):

You can use toggle instead;

```
$('#text').toggle();
```

With no parameters, the `.toggle()` method simply toggles the visibility of elements

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using toggle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x5qYz/

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Second Driver" id="driver" />
<input type="text" id="text" style="display:none;" />

$("#driver").click(function() {
    $('#text').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function()
{

    // Initially hide the text box
    $("#text").hide();

    $("#driver").click(function()
    {

         $("#text").toggle();
         return false; // We don't want to submit anything here!

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the textbox hidden when the page loads initially like this

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#text').hidden();
 });
```

Then your should work the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#driver').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting
        $('#text').show();
    });
});
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Add Second Driver" id="driver" />
<input type="text" id="text" />
```

Comment: can I show the textbox and label in a slow motion .. and yeh i dont want the form to be submit .

Comment: Yes. Just change the `.show()` to `.show('slow')`. Instead of the default `show` effect you can use `fadeIn` or `slideDown`.