# hide/unhide textbox with fadein/fadeout effect on a click of a button

Tags: jquery

I've read this reference
[Using Jquery to hide/unhide the textbox if button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6519212/881879)
which led to this answer
http://jsfiddle.net/x5qYz/
however I would like to add fade in and fade out effect to the hide/unhide process
how do I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have said, fadeToggle(). I added some extra to this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x5qYz/2/

It wont allow user to constantly click the button to screw up the animation. User can press it only once and when animation is complete, he can press it second time.

**Answer to the question in comments:**
http://jsfiddle.net/x5qYz/7/

Comment: thanks, i will try it.-- now If i want it to show on the button itself, I mean the button disappear and change to a textbox. then if they click outside the area, textbox gone, button reappear. how do I do that

Comment: @skeith added that to my answer. Please accept it if you feel it is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You want the .fadeToggle(): http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/x5qYz/1/

Answer (score 0):

use function

```
fadeToggle()
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

Answer (score 0):

You could use this jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready = function() {
    $('#text').hide();

    $("#driver").click(function() {
        $('#text').fadeToggle();
    });

}();
</script>
```

And to stop it from fading in and out constantly after rapidly clicking the button a lot, use this jQuery which will stop it from doing that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready = function() {
    $('#text').hide();

    $("#driver").click(function() {
        $('#text').stop(true,true).fadeToggle();
    });

}();
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, however people still can click it again right? but not rapidly

Comment: @skeith Yeah, people can definitely click it again. It's just when you click it a lot really fast, it messes up the whole div. But the .stop will make it stop when they keep clicking and keep it visible instead of flashing in and out. It basically stops it from getting a bunch of animations built up in the queue on one element that is caused when clicking a lot in a row fast. You can try taking out `.stop(true,true)` for a second and then click it a lot really fast and see what happens, it's not good, but the `.stop(true,true)` fixes that. :)